# Возможно ли как-нибудь для Oracle Database провести процедуру сжатия БД?

Tags: oracle

Возможно ли провести какой-нибудь там тюниг/дефрагментацию и сжатие чтобы сократить занимаемый БД размер.

Comment: Нашел один вариант, exec dbms_space.database_level_shrink; если еще есть пишите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Сжатие таблиц](http://www.codenet.ru/db/oracle/Oracle-Compress.php)
- [Сокращение занимаемого места](http://ora-20000.blogspot.ru/2009/04/tablespace.html)